# Removing escape characters from a string (xml) and sending it to a WCF service

Tags: xml, wcf, http, service, http-post

I'm trying to make a POST http request to my WCF Service and send ti some data in XML. I tried building an XML string both using XmlWriter and just string concatenation, but I always have escaping characters (\" and other) in my string, and so my POST fails.

This is how I build an XML String:

```
        var data = string.Empty;
        data += (@"<Root xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/..."" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">");
        data += (String.Format("<Element1>{0}</Element1>", element1));
        data += (String.Format("<Element2>{0}</Element2>", element1));
        data += (String.Format("<Element3>{0}</Element3>", element1));
        data += (String.Format("<Element4>{0}</Element4>", element4));
        data += (String.Format("</Root>"));
```

and I get \" characters in Root element because of xmlns attribute and its value. That's why my POST alaways returns 400 Bad Request. This is how I make a POST:

```
        var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);

        req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.Method = "POST";

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        var os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        os.Flush();
        os.Close();

        var response = _GetResponseString(req.GetResponse());

        return response;
```

How to get rid of unwanted characters and make this POST working?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting \" characters? Or is it the watch window display of the data? Try enabling tracing on the server side to see what exactly the server is complaining about to consider the request bad.

Comment: Yeah you were right, it was not because of \" characters, the message was too big. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed in the comments, the problem wasn't the escaped characters (it's usually a red herring that the watch window in VS shows them as if they were escaped), but something else.

Almost all the time where you have a problem where a WCF service is returning a 400 / 500 error to the client, [enabling tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) should point you to the right direction in fixing the issue.